# Regex for extracting the region name from an AWS ARN

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a RegEx that extracts the region (us-east-1) from the following AWS ARN:

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789012:secret:catsndogs-3HieNb
```

I've tried using `([^:]*)` which creates groups, but I can't seem to grab the value of the 4th group, i.e. us-east-1.

Comment: If, as in the example, the desired between-colons text, and no undesired between-colons text, is always follows by a colon, one or more digits and another colon, you could use a positive lookahead: `[^:]*(?=:\d+:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Since the OP did not specify a regex flavor, the following assumes PCRE; minor differences can arise if one changes the flavor; for instance, Golang uses `$1` instead of `\1` to refer to the first capturing group.)

```
^(?:[^:]+:){3}([^:]+).*
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Apyhb8/1)

- `^` is to start matching at the beginning of the line
- `(?:[^:]+:){3}` matches 3 repetitions of `(?:[^:]+:)`, which is a non-capturing group containing the regex `[^:]+:`, which matches a sequence of 1 or more non `:` followed by a `:`;
- `([^:]+)` matches and captures the 4th occurrence of that pattern
- `.*` matches all the rest of the line

If the substitution expression is `\1`, all the line will be substituted by the 4th `:`-separated field.

Comment: cannot get this to work - tried with grep and it always returns the entire arn:
`arn="arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3"
grep -oP '^(?:[^:]+:){3}([^:]+).*' <<< "$arn"`
output: `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3`

Comment: @Kappacake, have you read the disclaimer in the first paragraph?

Comment: Yes, you are assuming PCRE (unless I missed something). Unfortunately that doesn't help me in figuring out what's wrong with my command or what the entire command should be.

Comment: Found a much simpler solution: `echo "$arn" | cut -d':' -f4`

Comment: @Kappacake, yeah, regex are not necessarily the best tool to solve any problem.